# Using the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem for groups to prove an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-spaces

Let $G$ be the group of all real matrices of the form $ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix} $ with $ac \ne 0$, under matrix multiplication. Let $H$ be the subgroup consisting of all the elements in which $a=c=1$. Use the Fundamental Theorem to show that $ G/H \cong (\Bbb R \setminus \{0\},*) \times (\Bbb R \setminus \{0\},*)$.

It isn't that I want the answer. I'm looking for a certain strategy to develop when facing questions of the form "$G/H \cong something$".

Comment: Usually you first find a map from $G$ onto the "*something*" for which you can then you show what maps to zero is exactly things in $H$.

Comment: Side note: Matrices of this form are important in Gaussian (linear) optics. The group $G$ represents telescopic systems, while with $a=c=1$ they represent translations between optical elements.

Answer (score 1):

The typical strategy is to leverage the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) by finding a homomorphism of $G$ onto the second group. I guess this is the 'fundamental theorem' you're referring to.

After picking such a map, you can compute the kernel and see what $H$ must be. Here, in this case, you're given what the kernel is, and that suggests what the homomorphism ought to be. If you map $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}\mapsto (a,c)$, then $H$ would indeed be the kernel of that map. The only thing to ensure the candidate map you've chosen is actually a group homomorphism.